# Github: is this workflow with sub-modules right? can be better?

Tags: git, version-control, process, git-submodules

I have a project A that uses lib B

- project A <-- main repository

  - some sub folder

    - lib B <-- sub module
- lib B <-- main repository

Now both are in source control, they are github repositories.

- Now lib B is not completed, I just add things as I need in project A, as I always edit the lib B in the sub module, I've added this instead of the main repository because in the git for windows you are only allowed to have only one of them.
- Now I make a push to the lib B from sub module
- I remove lib B as submodule from git
- add lib B as main repository, now I pull.
- Then I add lib B as sub module to the git
- restart!

I really think this process is bad, and can be improved but don't know how...
Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with submodules I would just use git from the command line like it was designed to be used. This way all you have is the top level repo with the one submodule in it and you just push and pull from these 2 places.

Comment: You mean, maintain the same structure, but instead of using the graphical win github, use the command line to push from the submodule and pull in the main repository?

Comment: yes. the key being that you have full freedom of the locations of the repos. If you take the time to learn to use it from the command line, you will be better off for it in the end.